# How to read tag's value in cucumber hooks method

Tags: cucumber, hook, cucumber-java

I am passing tags for my cucumber BeforeActions hooks @Before that I want to use as a parameter inside the Before method.

```
@Before("@requireLogin")
    public void defaultLogin() {
          do login here;
    }

@Before("@newUserA")
    public void login() {
          do login with a user called "newUserA";
    }
```

In first @Before I am using default Login user but in another @Before I want to send a tag as a hint to use that user as a username for login.

Now I am not sure how do I read that "newUserA" inside login method.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a tag to login. Login is business functionality and needs to be mentioned in each scenario where it is required. If you have lots of scenarios that need you to be logged in you can put the login step in the background. e.g.

```
Feature: Admin xxx

Background:
  Given I am logged in as an admin

Scenarios Do foo
  When I foo
   ...

Scenario: Do bar
  When I bar
```

You can then use a number of different login steps to clearly specify the different needs you might have, and if you are really clever you can have each step def delegate the work to a helper method so you avoid duplicate code e.g.

```
# Login Steps

Given "I login as an admin" do
  @i = create_user(role: 'admin')
  login as: @i
end

Given "I login as Fred" do
  @fred = create_user(first_name: 'Fred')
  login as: @i
end

Given "Fred is logged in" do
  # this one assumes that Fred has already been created
  login as: @fred
end

...
```

The actor (person who is doing stuff) and whether or not they are logged in, is far too important to be left out of the scenario language. I'd strongly suggest you change your approach here and not use tagging for this.
  @

Comment: Yes, I've changed my approach. Thanks for your guidance.
But I can't read tag's value inside the method, can I?

Comment: the @i, @fred etc in my answer are global variables that allow communication between steps, they are not tags